# How to save objects in internal memory?

Tags: android, save

My Course class has 4 fields :

```
String name;
String startHour
String startEnd
String day
```

I need to save objects of this class and load it every time the user starts the application with the saved objects.
In addition, the user can add or delete objects (that is , add/remove courses).

What's the best way to do it ? SharedPrefernces ? JSon ?

Answer (score 1):

Since user can add/delete/modify, using a database would be your best option, SQLite is what you want.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: What will be the primary key ? Two courses can have the same name but different times. SQLite is not object oriented, as i know...

Comment: If i'll attach every course object an id , how will i know to assign an id that hasn't been assigned already ?

Comment: The primary key will just be an auto-incremented integer.  http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html